# Error during RNNLib configuration: netcdfcpp.h cannot be found

Tags: makefile, netcdf

When attempting to compile RNNLib, I got an error in NetcdfDataset.hpp:26:24 saying that Netcdfcpp.h could not be found. I looked around and found a bug report from 2011 that suggested that this was a bug, but it claimed to have been fixed. I have tried everything I can think of, including rebuilding NetCDF (a dependency of RNNLib) with various different flags, and have been unable to fix this bug. Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble on a virtual machine building rnnlib.
I had to install the C and C++ version of NetCDF to get it to work.

The C version can be installed via `sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev`

I had to install the C++ version by building it.

Hope it will help. It's quite a difficult lib to install.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps someone: you can avoid some of the pain by installing packages from APT, and access the correct version mentioned by [user3620756](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23567000/5303618), which contains the `netcdfcpp.h` header file 
. This happens through a legacy package, available on Ubuntun 16.04 (Xenial universe, see [APT repository](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/xenial/universe/amd64/libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dev/4.2-4/?query=libnetcdf)).

First install `libnetcdf` for C, then install `libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dev` which should depend on `libnetcdf-c++4` and install required C++ libraries on the go:

```
sudo apt install libnetcdf-dev libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The newest version doesn't have this netcdfcpp.h file anymore.
I had to use ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-cxx-4.2.tar.gz to get it working.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as a link-only answer - he's linking to a different version, not to another post.

Answer (score 0):

I have also followed the same process and it worked for me
"The newest version doesn't have this netcdfcpp.h file anymore. I had to use ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-cxx-4.2.tar.gz to get it working."
After downloading the folder, I had to build it by entering into the netcdf folder. I used simple command for the task :
.\configure
make
sudo make install

But in the file named as "NetcdfDataset.hpp", I have to give the complete path of the `netcdfcpp.h` file. For my case the path of the include file is :

```
#include "/Volumes/Macintosh_HD_2/WordSpottingProj/trunk/CODE C++/rnnlib_source_forge_version/netcdf-cxx-4.2/cxx/netcdfcpp.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the context of trying to use a makefile that called for `netcdfcpp.h`:

```
$ make -f makefile_MAC
c++ -O2 -o burn7.x burn7.cpp -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lm -lnetcdf_c++
burn7.cpp:31:10: fatal error: 'netcdfcpp.h' file not found
#include <netcdfcpp.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [burn7.x] Error 1
```

I'm on a Mac, so I used Homewbrew to install the NetCDF package, but version 4.3.3.1 didn't appear to have `netcdfcpp.h`:

```
brew install homebrew/science/netcdf
```

However, I found that installing it with an additional flag resulted in this version being included:

```
brew install homebrew/science/netcdf --with-cxx-compat
```

I assume that the same is true of other installation/compilation methods, and not that this file has been taken out of versions since 4.2 as others answers state. Maybe it was a default option before and now it isn't?